# Accessing LinqToSql DataLayer in MVC2

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm relatively new to MVC design pattern and accessing LinqToSql data.  Basically I want to utilize the concepts of MVC to access data (which I have stored in a Linq2Sql DataContext) and populate the results to a gridview. Since code-behind files defeat the purpose of MVC, where exactly would I place my linq query to SELECT the data, and bind it to a gridview ?

This is my code for SELECT:
         public void getBills()
        {

```
        BillDataContext context = new BillDataContext();
        var bills =
            from b in context.Bill_Items
                select b;

    }
```

I tried putting this in a controller BUT obviously can't grab my gridView object from the controller. I'm trying hard not to strap a code-behind file to that View and go from there. Hopefully someone can shed some light on best practices for accomplishing this.

Comment: You will be using a View with Table scaffolding, not a `GridView`.  GridViews only work in ASP.NET, not ASP.NET MVC.  NerdDinner has an example that shows how to make a view and a repository that displays a grid of items here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/nerddinner/use-controllers-and-views-to-implement-a-listingdetails-ui  Look about 3/4 of the way down the page, in the section titled **"Implementing the Index View Template."**

Answer (score 1):

You could make a Repository class that will contain all your Linq code, and return your model objects.
Ex BillingRepository with a method called GetBillItems(..)

You can call this repository class from the controller and pass the model to the view

```
public ActionResult BillItems()
{
  BillingRepository repository = new BillingRepository();
  var model = repository.GetBilItems();
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: You need to explain to him that there's no GridView in ASP.NET MVC.  I'm in the process of writing an answer for that; do you want to tell him, or shall I complete my answer? :)

Comment: This way you can bind the model to your view, and there is no code in the view itself

Comment: You still need a view.  What do you mean, no code?  You still need something to display it, even if it's a rudimentary table with the `<% %>` donut holes.

Comment: I missed the gridView part, but figured he was just referring to a "table." Anyway, just complete your answer :-)

Comment: *[sigh]* It's been awhile... I'm a little rusty.  I'll see if I can copypasta some code from NerdDinner. :)

Comment: The point is that there will only be declarative markup in the view. No control flow or data access.

Comment: I was only trying to point out the controller/repo part. I assumed the view part was know :-) But obviously you still need a view. Granted it will be one with absolutely no logic..

Comment: Well, that's true.  I doubt the OP even knows what a View looks like though, if he's talking about GridViews.